# Oracle SQL - How to execute a query stored in a variable via command line

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I tried in many ways without success to execute the query stored in a variable:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 
Connected as xxx@yyy

SQL> declare
  2  var v_SQL := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  3  begin
  4  exec v_SQL;
  5  end;
  6  /

SQL> begin
  4  exec immediate 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  5  end;
  6  /

SQL> declare
  2  var v_SQL NVARCHAR := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
  3  begin
  4  exec immediate v_SQL;
  5  end;
  6  /
```

It throws generally the following error:

> ORA-06550: line 2, column 11:
> PLS-00103: Symbol "NVARCHAR2" encountered when one of the following is expected:
>
> ```
> := . ( @ % ; not null range default character
> ```
>
> The symbol ":=" has been replaced by "NVARCHAR2" to continue.
> ORA-06550: line 5, column 6:
> PLS-00103: Symbol "V_SQL" encountered when one of the following is expected:
>
> ```
> := . ( @ % ;
> ```

Comment: You are mixing up SQL\*Plus family *client* commands like `var[iable]` and `exec[ute]`, with PL/SQL constructs like `begin`/`end`, declaring local PL/SQL variables, and `execute immediate` - which is unrelated to the client ``exec`. It's not clear if you really want PL/SQL - what will you do with the results of the query, and why is it in a variable at all?

Comment: I need to drop several tables, the idea is to put those statements into that variable

Answer (score 1):

You syntax should be -

```
declare
       v_SQL VARCHAR2(100) := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
begin
     execute immediate v_SQL;
end;
/
```

This will not throw the error but will not produce any result. You have to use SYS_REFCURSOR to get the result from a table in oracle. So your correct code should look alike -

```
declare
       v_SQL VARCHAR2(100) := 'SELECT * FROM DUAL';
       v_result SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
     open v_result for v_SQL;;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Executing a *query* that returns data requires an extra step for putting the data *into* something. But since you're only executing DDL commands, you can use PL/SQL like this:

```
declare
    v_sql clob := 'drop table temp_table1';
begin
    execute immediate v_sql;
end;
/
```